# Can compressed air be used as a weapon?

Tags: weapons, combat, air, swords

Obviously guns or similar weapons can use air to propel projectiles, but I'm thinking more about close combat, or even a medieval setting, or generally less technologically advanced setting.

If someone could control air particles and compress them could they become as hard as a sword? I remember finding that it compresses from 1 to 414 bars but I couldn't find any details on its properties at this pressure.

So. Could compressed air be used as a weapon at this pressure?

Comment: It looks like you're asking a lot of different questions. Can you [edit] your post so that you're asking 1 specific question? We have a strict 1 question per post policy.

Comment: @sphennings np done.

Comment: @ProjectApex I hadn't actually thought about making it a solid. Wouldn't it need to be cooled though? And compressing it would cause it to increase in temperature?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. So would it be more effective to burn enemies than use like a sword?

Comment: 1 to 414 bar is a **very** broad range of pressures. Can you specify a particular pressure?

Comment: @sphennings Well 1 bar is about the pressure at sea level on earth. Idk what pressure level would begin to have an effect on the air. But what would happen at 400 bars would be useful as I'm assuming that then at less pressure it would have similar effect just with less intensity.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan Wow how did I not think of that lol *face palm*. Thanks I'll note that

Answer (score 11):

According to [safety sheets](http://ehso.emory.edu/content-guidelines/Toolbox/ToolboxTraining_CompressedAirSafety.pdf) one can find in the mare magnum of internet, compressed air bears its own risks

> Hazards of compressed air and compressed air equipment
>
> - Flying particles and debris – can result in eye injuries,
>   cuts/scrapes or other significant injuries to almost any body part;
> - High pressure air – can result in air injection into the body
>   leading to potential injuries such as air embolism, ruptured ear
>   drums or organs, and dislodged eye balls;
> - High noise – can result in temporary or permanent hearing loss.

Some time ago in my country an event hit the news where a group of teenagers ruptured the intestine of a fellow by improperly using an air compressor.

For sure compressed air is dangerous. The shock wave of an explosion is also nothing more than a front of compressed air propagating around the explosion.

However the effect of compressed air is not due to "be hard as a sword": compressed air, left free, will tend to expand and nullify the pressure gradient.

Comment: Dislodge eyeballs, holy cow

Comment: The whole "air compressor up the rear end" thing actually [came up on the Darwin awards](https://darwinawards.com/darwin/darwin2008-22.html) a while back.

Comment: People party hard in your country, Dutch.

Answer (score 7):

With regard to the question "*If someone could control air particles and compress them could they become as hard as a sword?*", air is made up of mostly nitrogen and oxygen.  Both can form solids, usually by freezing, but also at room temperature by exerting tremendous pressure; you'd probably want only one or the other since a mixture would probably be weaker than either alone.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_nitrogen and the high temp. phase diagram https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Phase-diagram-of-nitrogen_fig7_7991288
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen (phase diagram included)

A causal glance at the [phase diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram) shows pressures required at room temperature starting in the range of over 2-3 gigpascals or, equivalently, over ~19,000-~27,000 atmospheres (for comparison, the pressure at the bottom of the Mariana Trench is "only" about ~1,100 atm) for the [phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(matter)) of each that form at the lowest possible pressure.   So, technically, yes, a sword shaped solid could be formed by expending a tremendous amount of energy.

Would it be as strong as a steel sword?  Seems unlikely; the few numbers found for compressive or tensile strength for these solidified gasses are vastly lower than the corresponding strengths for ordinary sword steels.  So it would probably break on impact with anything significant.

Bonus commentary: However, this sword-like object is still a fearsome weapon.  Remember all the energy needed to compress the air into a sword and hold it there?  Releasing that compression causes the air to flash back into a gas instantly, so the "sword" is in actuality an immensely powerful bomb.  The best way to use it would probably to be to chuck it at your enemies and run for the hills.

Comment: The underlying assumption is that the energy is release "instantly". Which may or may not happen.

Comment: Thanks thats really helpful. Yeah I'm getting the feeling with that much power a sword shape isn't the best option

Comment: There was some guy wandering around town earlier handing out free swords made out of some strange material. As soon as he finished, he left very quickly. I wonder why he did that.

Answer (score 6):

Bit of a paradigm shift, but there exists a modern-day melee weapon that very effectively utilizes compressed air as a weapon

[The WASP Knife](https://www.knifecenter.com/item/WIWASPKA/wasp-injection-knife-fixed-bead-blast-blade-black-neoprene-handle)

It was designed as a defence against shark attacks for divers. It uses a small CO2 canister in the handle to dump a load of rapidly expanding air inside the target.

Obviously this has deeply unpleasant effects on biological body, and the knife is illegal in a whole lot of jurisdictions.

I can see someone with the ability to compress and direct the flow of air using a weapon with a similar concept. You fight with the weapon as normal, but when you land a hit, you blast air through a small channel in the tip of the blade.

Answer (score 3):

## Trinitramide.

The name of this compound is a little confusing to those with  a biological background, since what we think of as "amides" are really "carboxamides".  It might be more straightforward (if not chemically correct) to think of [trinitramide](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/new-molecule-could-propel-rockets/3002850.article) as "trinitronitrogen".  It would appear that in your world, the person who invented trinitrotoluene (TNT) went on to bigger and better (and probably much less stable) things.

Anyway, it is at best [unclear](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/new-molecule-could-propel-rockets/3002850.article) whether trinitramide could exist as a stable solid, which means that wishful thinking prevails.  We can condense down N2 and O2 from the atmosphere, work a little magic, and swing around a sword made out of something extreme ... among oxidizers used for rockets.  But eco-friendly!

However brief the entertainment provided, *anyone* should be nervous to be hit with such a sword.

Answer (score 2):

[Vortex ring gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_ring_gun#:%7E:text=The%20vortex%20ring%20gun%20is,marking%20ink%20or%20other%20chemicals.) Disregarding compressing air into a solid to make a weapon. And this may be of no use at all to you though the first thing that came to mind when I read the question title was the vortex guns and Hail gun, experimented on in WWII. Used for AAA they would project a large vortec/torrid/death doughnut at high velocity at bomber formations literally knocking the plains out of the air... (In theory).
Hail guns, which have actually recently see somewhat of a resurgence. Were supposedly used to disrupt hail formation in thunder cloud before they would release any forming hail and became damaging.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with trying to make a sword out of compressed air is, What's going to keep it in that shape?

If you're assuming that the air is compressed by some magic power, maybe you could. Who knows what magic can do? Pretty much anything you say you want it to do.

But if you're trying to be more "hard science", sure, you could have some machine that compressed air into the shape of a sword. But then what? Once you take the "sword" out of the machine into the open air, all that compressed air is quickly going to dissipate. You could have some metal casing around it that keeps it in the sword shape. But the casing would have to be sword-shaped to keep the air in that shape, and it would have to be strong enough to contain the compressed air. At which point why not just use the casing as a sword and forget the compressed air?

Compressed air can be used to propel projectiles as it escapes from a container. Like a BB gun.

A sufficiently strong blast of air could knock someone over. If you knocked him hard enough or far enough or over a cliff or some such that could be useful as a weapon.

A tight enough blast of compressed air could injure someone directly. Especially if you blast him in a sensitive place, like the eyes or the ears.

Maybe a sufficiently creative person could come up with a way to make an air compressor into a truly effective weapon. I can't think of one. Using it to fire projectiles seems to me the most effective thing you could do. If you didn't have gunpowder available that might be a good weapon. Otherwise, hitting someone over the head with your air compressor is probably more effective than most other uses.

Comment: I was imagining that he wouldn't hold it as a sword. More like a superhero that controls daggers with their mind, but a blade of wind instead

Answer (score 1):

"control air particles" to form a sword?  That is far future technology or very strong magic.  No way for anything "medieval".  If we allow air pressure technology ...

The Giradoni Air Rifle (Lewis & Clark, *Austrian Army* from 1780 for 30-ish years) was a repeating, serious weapon.  Pull lever to drop bullet from tubular magazine, shoot, repeat.  20-shot magazine, 30 shot worth of pressure, pressure chamber exchangeable on the fly.

I can totally see a world with air-powered 6-shooters.
Or air-pressure enhanced close combat weapons.

For example: A piercing weapons (lance, dagger, ...) that upon being rammed into a body or armour, triggers a mechanism using the power of compressed air to:

- ram the head of the weapon forward, increasing penetration, armour piercing and damage
- play hypodermic needle and insert pressured air into the body of the enemy
- ram a bullet/needle/small spear deep(er) into the target
- combine any of these with noxious or poisonous substances

Depending on the design, it may be usable for some more shots or need re-setting or re-arming to work (at all or properly) again.

A piercing or straight punching weapon could also be activated by a manual trigger, adding air pressure power to your jab or stab, by expanding the business end from the rest on command --- ideally so the maximum speed of the head is reached when contact is made.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Stricly speaking...

- Let's take an average sword volume of 300 cm3
- The volumic mass of **solid N2** (**at 0 atm and -252°C**): 1.025 g.cm-3
- This leads to a sword of approximatively 0.3 kg.
- Volumic mass of gazeous N2 is 1.1848.10-3 g.cm-3 (under normal conditions of temperature and pressure.)
- Which mean we need 0.364 m3 of N2 if we "use" 100% of this volume's atoms.
- As N2 compose 78.06% of air in volume, we need 0.467 m3 of air that we lower to -252°C to create your weapon.

So if you may archieve to get a sword by this method, your question was about a pressure change.
Unfortunatly for you, it may be impossible to reach the solid state for air at regular temperature. Take a look a this phase diagramme for nitrogen:

[image]

Even at -70°C (minimum temperature you can "reasonably" reach on Earth in a medieval setting), you see that rising the pressure will get you to supercritical state but never to the solid one. For instance, you mention a pressure of 410 bar which is equal to 41 MPa: even if air and nitrogen don't strictly have to the same properties, this is right in the middle of the supercritical state...